# How handle a non-resumable ordered delivery send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Has anyone got an elegant way to resolve an ordered delivery send port (with stop sending subsequent messages ticked) that has suspended (non-resumeable)?

Please let me know how you handle it. Do you use any tools, or created any custom  tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good way out of the box. We have developed some utility to save these messages in case required using BizTalk Explorer OM, however BizTalk Explorer OM also has a limitation of saving only 50 messages in one single service instance. So your best bet is to make sure you have a way to replay those messages from outside by keeping a copy of message.